# VS2015: Connect to Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

Как подсоединится в VS2015 к удаленному приватному репозиторию на Bitbucket-e?

Устанавливаю в Team Explorer > Settings > Git > Repository Settings > Remotes > Add параметры:

Fetch: https://bitbucket.org/{team_id}/{storage_name}

Push: https://bitbucket.org/{team_id}/{storage_name}

При попытке сделать push и запроса User / Pwd к сайту: bitbucket.org
возникает ошибка: "Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)."

P.S. Также установлен SSH key на bitbucket.org.

Также пишут что VS2015 не работает через SSH, поэтому необходимость его настройки сомнительна.

SSH Config:

```
Host bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Stack trace по подключению через SSH:

```
>ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org

...
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username: *bitbucket_user_login*
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 149
Enter passphrase for key '/cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa':
debug1: Trying private key: /cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Еще проблема с ssh-agent(ом):

```
>ssh-agent -s
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-djump24624/agent.24624; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=28000; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 28000;

>ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Вид из Git-Bash (c Git-Bash проблема решена через Run as administrator):

```
xxx@LocalPC MINGW64 ~
$ cd ~/.ssh/

xxx@LocalPC MINGW64 ~/.ssh
$ dir
config  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts

xxx@LocalPC MINGW64 ~/.ssh
$ ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for bitbucket.org
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.167] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:*bitbucket_user_login*
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 149
Load key "/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: ssh -T git@bitbucket.org что выводит ?

Comment: Пишет что: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: Значит вы не настроили ssh. Вам нужно или добавить ключи в ~/.ssh/cofing или поменять origin на https, тогда каждый раз при коммите будет запрашиваться логин и пароль

Comment: Студия запрашивает Login/PWD и это ей не помогает, но Atlassian SourceTree каким то образом работает же. Не совсем понятно нужно ли для студии SSH настраивать каким то образом или нет.

Comment: Какой плагин используется для студии ? Atlassian SourceTree работает через putty. А студия по другому

Comment: Написано в Options > Source Control: Microsoft Git Provider (ставил Git Extensions for VS2015)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31144/discussion-between-exileed-and-cpp-user).

Comment: С чатом проблема - требует какой то дополнительной авторизации.

Comment: У вас случайно 2FA не стоит? я бы в место пароля использовал токен. Я настраивал когда-то так . добавил в ~/.ssh/config Host workid 
HostName bitbucket.org 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workid
Host workid 
HostName bitbucket.org 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workid
после этого заработало. Нужно только конвертировать ключ в openssh

Comment: Теперь другая проблема: 0644 "warning: unprotected private key file" for key ~/.ssh/id_rsa Это как то решается под Win7?

Comment: chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa или куда вы ключ положили

Comment: chmod.exe - Системная ошибка - Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует cygintl-2.dll. Попробуйте переустановить программу.

Comment: Под виндой нету chmod-a

Comment: Да и ssh нету. в git консоли есть

Comment: Добавил Stack Trace в описание.

Comment: Студия ssh не поддерживает (вроде бы), да и remote у вас прописан как https, а не как ssh. так что все связанное с ssh в вопросе не имеет отношения к проблеме.

Comment: для https - 401 - это скорее всего просто неправильное имя или пароль. особенно если при этом диалог запроса пароля появляется два раза.

Comment: @PashaPash: Согласен, об этом упомянул в описании, но возможно решив проблему с ssh это даст понять проблему с https.

Comment: @cpp_user маловероятно. там совершенно независимые протоколы и совершенно независимые настройки (и проблемы)

Comment: @cpp_user попробуйте сделать git push из командной строки (из обычного cmd, открыть его из списка репозиториев в студии, а не из bash!) - там должно так же спросить имя и пароль, но в обход студийного credentials helper. если сработает - проверяйте что у вас вписано как cred helper в конфиге - возможно, имя и пароль просто не доходят до гита.

Comment: @PashaPash: Что значит "открыть его из списка репозиториев в студии"?

Comment: @cpp_user Team Exporer / Manage Connections / Local Git Repos / Right Click на имени репозитория / Open Command Prompt

Comment: А формат команды там какой?

Comment: @cpp_user просто `git push`. или `git push origin master`

Comment: С консоли работает, а чего с GUI то не хочет.

Comment: Да и пароль вводить запарывает.

Comment: @cpp_user если cmd-консоли работает, а из студии - нет, то скорее всего cred helper кривой. попробуйте вычистить запомненные пароли из `Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager\Windows Credentials`. Если не поможет - ловите process explorer-ом - что именно запускает студия. Если совсем никак - попробуйте указать урл к репозиторию как `https://username:password@bitbucket.org/your_repo_name`

Comment: Windows Credentials очистил не помогло, URL тоже менял - не помогает.

Answer (score 2):

не знаю как там в VS2015 , но знаю , что для bitbucket.org нужно конкретно прописывать IdentityFile , только после этого с репом можно общаться нормально .

путь к репу :

```
git@bitbucket.org:{user}/{rep}.git
```

Прописать ключ для bitbucket.org

```
$ cd .ssh
$ touch config
$ nano config 
Host bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: PS . По поводу поддержки SSH , если таковой нет - то видимо и не надо , ставите на локальную машину git и свободно клонируете реп с bitbucket.org , предварительно настроив ssh . Ну а с локальной версией гита у VS2015 проблем не возникнет точно .

Comment: Что значит с "Ну а с локальной версией гита у VS2015 проблем не возникнет точно"? Microsoft Git Provider почему не справляется с этой задачей? Если имеется ввиду использовать стороннюю программу так для этого есть Atlassian Source Tree которая тоже хорошо справляется с задачей, но хотелось бы более тесной интеграции VS2015 с Bitbucket. По умолчанию VS2015 интегрируется только с GitHub или TFS.

Comment: Конечно может , но вы правильно заметили он зависит от предустановленных интеграций с сервисами . Под локальным гитом я имел в виду [git-bash](http://git-for-windows.github.io/) , у которого на борту привычный функционал cmd , клонируйте на локал что хотите и от куда хотите и ваш Microsoft Git Provider будет все это будет видеть.

Comment: Вижу вы сверху дали Stack trace . пропишите вручную в конфиге (/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/config)  
Host bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: Все это было уже прописано в c/Users/xxx/.ssh/config и в итоге выходит такой stack trace.

Comment: Просто неп увидел в вашем trace строчки типа `debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1`

Comment: Поставил git-bash ничего не поменялось, Git CMD выдает такой же самый Stack Trace и в VS2015 никаких изменений, по прежнему выдает: 401 (Unauthorized).

Comment: Решил попробовать соединится с виндовой тачки , малоли . и ... никаких проблем ... прилагаю лог . [ssh_log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gb888i2u4nvldvl/ssh_log.txt?dl=0)  гдето вы с ключами напутали , либо в конфиге ssh их не прописали .

Comment: Atlassian Source Tree с этими ключами без проблем работает через PuTTY.

Comment: Можете показать свой ssh config ?

Comment: Добавил в описание + обнаружил еше проблему с агентом: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: Это не проблема

Comment: Почему? Возможно из-за агента и не подымается подключение.

Comment: ну у меня тоже самое , и не мешает . Я смотрю у вас ключи лежат в /cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/  . В конфиге прописано ~/.ssh/id_rsa , вы когда в консоли набираете cd ~/.ssh/ вы попадаете в папку /cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/ ?

Comment: Виндовый cd не понимает такого пути, но это же конфиг и путь уже разбирает сам SSH на свое усмотрение, но если явно указать путь с:\Users\xxx\.ssh\id_rsa в конфиге то это ничего не меняет, ошибка остается. P.S. Если указать намеренно неправильный путь то он показывает совсем другой лог и не спрашивает passphrase.

Comment: я имел в виду git-bash консоль , для данного клиента все ключи и конфиг должны лежать именно там с:\Users\xxx\.ssh\

Comment: Добавил Git-Bash консоль.

Comment: хех , тоесть с этими же ключами на данный момент другой клиент норм конектится а git-bash не хочет , попробуйте нагенерить еще 1 голый ключик с уникальным именем и залейте его на bitbucket . в консоли git-bash => `ssh-keygen` и его имя в конфиг заместо `id_rsa`

Comment: Это я уже делал не помогает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31270/discussion-between-redroid-and-cpp-user).

Comment: Спрашивайте здесь, думаю всем будет интересно знать.

Comment: порядок действий :  1. http://prntscr.com/90hbeh 2. http://prntscr.com/90hcd8 3. http://prntscr.com/90hczq 4. http://prntscr.com/90hdtn

Comment: Так и сделал был, с этими ключами работает SourceTree через Putty agent-a.

Comment: Думаю что проблема в ssh-agent, то ли он не работает то ли не видит ключ.

Comment: ох , я в отчаяние ... можно на последок полный лог с git-bash сонсоли ?

Comment: О ! теперь понятней `key_load_public: No such file or directory`

Comment: Это откуда видно?

Comment: `debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory` и именно он несуществующий участвует в авторизации `Load key "/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied`

Comment: Это в Bash-e, а в обычной консоли спрашивал же passhrase.

Comment: Также не понятно почему key public, если он private.

Comment: потому что в обычной консоли он у вас смотрит на файл который есть ,  и определяя что у файла есть секретная фраза он выводил в терминал вопрос passhrase , существующий файл у Вас лежит в '/cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa' , надо скопипастить его , ну или симилинк кинуть , хз есть такое в винде тока =(

Comment: И что делать теперь?

Comment: Bash не понимает команду: cd /cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/.ssh

Comment: `cp -r /cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa ~/ssh/id_rsa` `cp -r /cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/ssh/id_rsa.pub`  пробовать , я могу только гадать , в linux традиционно все проще .

Comment: cp: cannot stat ‘/cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa’: No such file or directory

Comment: пути видимо нужно промапить `/cygdrive/c/windows` => `c:\windows`

Comment: под виндой не может быть такого пути: /cygdrive/c/Users, потому что диск C:\ это уже и есть корень. реальный виндовый путь это C:\Users\

Comment: Да , понятно . `/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa` и `/c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` или `~/.ssh/id_rsa` и `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` нужно чтобы были ключи . проверяй через `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: cat: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa: Permission denied Вообще не понимаю почему Git-Bash for Windows не может работать с виндовыми путями.

Comment: a попробуйте Git-Bash от имени администратора запустить , мб тогда читаться будут ключики

Comment: Заработал Git-Bash под администратором - удалось подключится к Bitbucket-у, но увы это не помогает виндовой cmd.

Comment: ну и фиг с ней , git-bash норм же .

Comment: Мне вообще то нужно чтобы студия могла работать, но то что помогло башу не помогает ни виндовой cmd ни студии.

Comment: Ну так переходите в требуемый каталог и делайте `git clone git@bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx.git` , указываете в студии эту папку в качестве проекта . Далее пишите код комитаете все так же в консоли и пушите обратно в реп .

Comment: С локальным git-ом студия нормально работает, а вот чтобы одновременно закомитить локально и запушить удаленно на bitbucket уже не выходит из-за ошибки доступа к bitbucketу, поэтому pushить на bitbucket нужно с отдельного приложения SourceTree что не очень то удобно в работе но не то чтобы критично.

Comment: запускайте студию от админа . Я вот наоборот не люблю всякие там GUI , консольно как то удобней + я пушу частенько в разные репы и на все это у меня свой bash , считаю что дописать пару строк профитней чем разбираться с чужим творчеством , Но это опять же дело вкуса .

Comment: "запускайте студию от админа" - это не помогает решить проблему. У меня по сути зеркало на удаленный репозиторий - ветки по именам совпадают с локальным, зоопарков стараюсь не допускать.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio умеет обращаться к git репозиториям только по HTTPS и не умеет работать с SSH. Инструкция по клонированию репозитория есть [в другом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573583/106).

Comment: По HTTPS студия не просит ввести логин/пароль(секурити диалог не появляется), а тупо отваливается по: "Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)."