# Подключение bitbucket к visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, git, bitbucket

Как подключить существующий репозиторий с bitbucket к проекту в visual studio, и управлять изменениями из студии?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Заходите в репозиторий на Битбакете, в меню слева кликаете на Clone, выбираете HTTP и копируете ссылку (аналогично и для Гитхаба/Гитлаба/любого другого репозитория -- нужна http ссылка на репозиторий):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем в Team Explorer выбираете создание нового репозитория:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В разделе Local Git Repositories выбираете Clone, указываете ссылку на репозиторий и куда клонировать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Готово.

Comment: А через SSH студия не может или просто вы не рекомендуете?

Comment: @NickVolynkin не может, только онлайновая [поддерживает](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate). В любом случае я так и не научился его готовить, поэтому везде пользуюсь https, благо есть галочка "запомнить логин/пароль" :).

Comment: согласен, ssh - не самоцель. Работает и ладно .